# Notation for the set of all sets

Tags: notation, set-theory

I know that it doesn't make sense mathematically (Russell's paradox), but is there any nice way or notation to express the set of all sets?

Edit: I want the set to contain itself, even though it might break some definition.

Comment: @MeeSeongIm this is not an answer to what was asked

Comment: As for how to notate the universal set itself, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set) suggests that there is no standard notation, but I like the look of $\mathcal{U}$ or $\mathbb{U}$.  @rschwieb yes it is, as the "set" spydon describes would be the power set of the universal set, using this notation: $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{U})$

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks. I see the subtle difference. The power set of the universal set notation is what spydon is looking for.

Comment: @MeeSeongIm not really... note that it says inclusion of a universal set is part of some nonstandard set theories.

Comment: If we had a universal set, it would already contain all sets: we wouldn't need to take its power set.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I think if we have a universal set $U$ then the sets in consideration would be $\wp(U)$.

Comment: That's not false, but if we have a universal set $U$ then $U = \wp(U)$, so it's redundant.

Comment: @MishaLavrov $U = \wp(U)$ never holds because $|U| < |\wp(U)|$. Think of $U$ as the base set and $\wp(U)$ as a $\sigma$-algebra on $U$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn That's a reason the universal set doesn't exist. If it did, it would contain all sets; every element of $\wp(U)$ is a set; so it would contain all of $\wp(U)$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I see. You were talking about a universal set as a "set of all sets" in some set theory whereas I was thinking of a universal set as is taught in intro to probability: the sample space.

Comment: For @TrevorGunn and Mee Seong Im: If we consider the universe of sets to be a collection of sets $U$ that is itself a set, then Cantor's theorem applies and $\lvert U\rvert < \lvert \wp(U)\rvert.$ But then $U$ is not really universal, since it does not contain itself. On the other hand, if we consider a collection $U$ of all sets that is a proper class, then Cantor's theorem doesn't apply and in fact $\lvert U\rvert = \lvert \wp(U)\rvert.$ The powerset of a proper class is itself a proper class that only contains those subcollections that are sets, not classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In set theory the *class* of all sets is often denoted $V$.

Comment: I see the question was a bit unclear from the beginning, I want the set to contain itself too. I have updated the question.

Comment: Well, if you want the set to contain itself too you're not just asking about _notation_, you're asking for a major revision in set theory. There is no notation for this in standard set theory because there's no such thing.

Comment: Alright, I guess this is the closest to what I want then, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This concept is usually referred to as a "class". This concept is formalized in [Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) which is essentially the usual [Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (ZF) + classes. The basic rule is a class is just some predicate. A set is a predicate restricted to a set. We also allow ourselves the axioms of ZF to define sets to avoid having a self-referential definition.

Every set is a class because if we have a set $\{x \in A : \phi(x)\}$ (i.e. the predicate $\phi$ restricted to the set $A$) then we have a class $\{x : x \in A \wedge \phi(x)\}$. What distinguishes a set from a "proper class" (a class that is not a set) is that sets are allowed to be members of other classes. That is, for a set $A$ we are allowed to talk about $A \in B$ where $B$ is a class. The class of all sets may be defined as
$$ C = \{A : A = A\}. $$

Russel's paradox tells us that the statement $C \in C$ leads to a contradiction. Since it doesn't make sense to talk about whether or not $C$ is a member of something, that makes $C$ a proper class.

Comment: Or put $C=\{S\colon S=S\}$ and it works even for non-well-founded set theories.

Comment: For a number analogy, consider the question "Notation the greatest natural number?" -- clearly there's no natural number greater than all natural numbers. But you can define '∞' to be a number greater than all naturals, by making it not natural.

Comment: I see that the question was a bit unclear from the beginning, I want the set to contain itself too. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

In category theory, you can refer to the category of all sets as “the category **Set**,” and its objects are precisely the “class of all sets”. I can’t remember what is popular for denoting the objects of a category, but I think obj(**Set**) is one option.

Comment: There are multiple "element of" notations acceptable among mathematicians, e.g., if $A$ is an object in the category $\textsf{Set}$, then $A\in \textsf{Set}$ or $A\in \text{ob}(\textsf{Set})$ are both acceptable.

Comment: It doesn't contain itself though, or does it?

Comment: It doesn't contain itself, because it's not a set (it's a class) and it only contains sets.

Comment: @spydon I don’t see that “containing itself” is a requirement of the question, rather I think it is a sign the user is groping for the right word “class of all sets”

Comment: @rschwieb I thought that was clear from referring to the paradox, but I have clarified it in the question now!

Comment: @spydon OK: I thought you were looking for the term in standard set theory. I figured wrong, sorry. You’ll notice that all the answers are along the same lines...